# Add and remove input dropdowns to a grails form

Tags: jquery, grails, controller, append, gsp

After quite a lot time trying. I decided to post a question.
Here is what I'd like to do:

- Add and remove dropdowns from a form.
- Remove the chosen dropdown from the form. This means that if the user has already made some selections, it should be possible to delete for instance just the dropdown with the "option 2" selected.

So far, based on an answer by Gregg on this [question] ([Adding table rows from a Grails Template on Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581300/adding-table-rows-from-a-grails-template-on-button-click)) I have a form that adds dropdowns to the form.

But as I didn't get it that well... the form I have just adds rows whit a while tag.

Here is the form:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3" id="resources">
            <div class="control-group box" id="control-group">
                <div class="controls" id="resource-grouper">
                    <g:render template="resource" model="[end:1]"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The rendered template: Each dropdown is inteded to have a button to add or remove itself from the form.

```
<%int i = 1 %>
<g:while test="${i <= end}">
<%i++%>
<div class="input-prepend">
<span class="add-on">
    <button class="btn btn-mini addResource" type="button" onclick="addResource();" >
        <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
    </button>
</span> <span class="add-on">
    <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button">
        <i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>
    </button>
</span>
<g:select name="resources" from="${org.pmo.sari.Resource.list()}" optionKey="id" size="1" value="${projectInstance?.resources*.id}" class="span10" />
</div>
</g:while>
```

The javascript (just for adding, so far):

```
function addResource(){

    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;

    $.get("/SARI/project/addResource", {end: end} ,function(html) {

        $('#control-group').append(html);
    });
}
```

The controller function

```
def addResource(){
    int max = params.end.toInteger()
    max = max + 1
    render(template: "resource", model: ['end': max])
}
```

If anyone has a solution or comment on the subject, it would be very helpful.

Comment: So, what's the current result and how it differs from your requirement?

Comment: Hello Eugene. Currently it is possible to add an aditional _resource  on button click. What I'd like is to make it possible to add or remove one of the "instances" (to call them someway), for instance, if the user clicks the button for a dropbox that has "option2" select, it should remove that specific dropdown. I was going to add an image, but still don't have enough points to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while... I got it done, with the help of JQuery. I'm posting the code just in case its useful to anyone... 
It works well... Although I think I should not be using the button's ids the way I'm doing it. Suggestions are welcome.

```
       $('button.resources').on('click',function(){
            var clickedButton = $(this),
                    resourceContainer = clickedButton.parent('div'),
                    selectCounter = $('select.resources').size();

            if(clickedButton.attr('id')=='add'){

                var selector = clickedButton.siblings('select'),
                        newSelectContainer = resourceContainer.clone(true);

                newSelectContainer.find('select').val(selector.val());
                resourceContainer.after(newSelectContainer);
                selectCounter = selectCounter + 1;

                if(selectCounter > 1){
                    $('button.resources#remove').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            }

            if(clickedButton.attr('id')=='remove'){
                if (selectCounter > 1){
                    resourceContainer.remove();
                    selectCounter = selectCounter - 1;
                    if(selectCounter == 1){
                        $('button.resources#remove').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

The fragment thats being cloned and appended:

```
<div class="fieldcontain" id="resources-container">
<label for="resources">
    <g:message code="project.resources.label" default="Resources" />
</label>
<button type="button" class="resources" id="add" >+</button>
<button type="button" class="resources" id="remove">-</button>
<g:select name="resources" class="resources" from="${someclass.list()}" optionKey="id" size="1" value="${someInstance?.resources*.id}"  />
</div>
```

The result allows to add dropdown boxes after the clicked, and to keep the selected value.